# Grails 2.0 run-app very slow performance

Tags: performance, grails, grails-2.0

I'm using Grails 2.0. I used to develop under Grails 1.3.7 but when running an application under Grails 2.0 the performance is very slow. A page can take more than 30 seconds to show and it's very embarrassing and unproductive.

I googled and I found that GSPs in 2.0 are in some cases 10 times slower than 1.3.7 ;
Greame explained that there is a new way of handling GSPs in dev mod, but when executing grails prod run-app I have almost the same problem.

What should I do to speed up development process ? I'm loosing too much time.

PS : My GRAILS_OPTS are "-‬server‭ -‬Xmx600M‭ -‬Xms600M‭ -‬XX:MaxPermSize=250m‭ -‬Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dserver.port=9090‭"‬

Comment: I just moved from 1.3.7 to 2.1.1 and I don't see any performance issues, rather I see imnprovement. Can you update to 2.1.1. Also can you convert all your actions to be methods instead of closures and see if that helps ?

Comment: Try profiling your app with, say, VisualVM. You cannot improve performance when you don't know which part to improve.

Comment: It's mainly GSPs that are very slow. There is also resources plugin that makes a lot of nose in the console

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I posted an small announcement on the mailing list about 20 minutes ago:
http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/GSP-Compilation-tt4632864.html#a4635595

This issue was fixed:
http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9423

Please test the performance of the latest 2.1.x snapshot build.

Try these

```
export GRAILS_OPTS="-server -noverify -XX:PermSize=256m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xmx600M -Xms600m -XX:+UseParallelGC -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true 
-Dsun.reflect.inflationThreshold=100000"
```

For me, the trick was to set Xmx and Xms to the same value and set the PermSize and MaxPermSize to the same value. sun.reflect.inflationThreshold helps with the permgen. (http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7878?focusedCommentId=66447&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-66447 in the Grails jira for the explanation)

btw. I filed this issue 10 mins ago:
http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9444
If it's interesting, please vote on the issue.

Comment: Thanks .. That supposes that I have migrate to 2.1 or 2.2 ?

Comment: Another question can we reduce running thread number ? With java-melody plugin i see 250 threads most of them waiting and will never be used. That slow down the application and takes a lot of memory. any idea ?

Comment: It's worth going to 2.1.x currently . 2.0.x gets only critical fixes and 2.1.x already has a lot of improvements over 2.0.x . Going from 2.0.x -> 2.1.x is pretty seemless since there aren't too many differences.

Comment: @FlareCoder: Where to run this command... in command prompt(under my project directory)?

Answer (score 3):

Grails 2.x is slower than 1.3.x for development mode because of the reloading improvements. It uses Spring-Loaded reloading agent that is similar to JRebel.

Make sure that your development laptop has enough memory (>4GB), a SSD and a fast i7 CPU.

Get a recent laptop with 16GB memory & a fast SSD and you won't be thinking of slowness anymore. I'd also recommend a i7 series CPU. That costs only about $1200 currently.

Comment: Looks like 2.1.1 is massively memory hungry. I am in i3(Windows 64-bit) laptop with 4GB RAM and using GGTS with -Xms2048m -Xmx2750m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m. My application is in development mode. So what configuration do you suggest for hosting a minimal 2.1.1 grails app ?

Comment: 4GB of memory? That's a ludicrous requirement.

Comment: I develop a dozen node.js apps on a single-core VPS with 1GB of RAM, and had to create a new 8GB quad-core VPS solely for developing a single Grails project!  2GB seems sufficient so far (checking free-m) but still, compared to node......  Thankfully I don't have to host this app myself when its done...

Answer (score 2):

To make sure you are using the latest fixes to the Spring-Loaded reloading agent, use Grails 2.1.x instead of Grails 2.0.x . For Grails 2.1.1 you might want to upgrade the Spring-Loaded reloading agent to a snapshot version.

You can get the latest snapshot from:
https://repo.springsource.org/snapshot/com/springsource/springloaded/springloaded-core/

Currently it's https://repo.springsource.org/snapshot/com/springsource/springloaded/springloaded-core/1.1.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/springloaded-core-1.1.1.BUILD-20120821.173635-2.jar .

Replace $GRAILS_HOME/lib/com.springsource.springloaded/springloaded-core/jars/springloaded-core-1.0.6.jar with the downloaded snapshot (rename the snapshot to the same file name springloaded-core-1.0.6.jar).

This answer will be outdated as soon as springloaded-core version 1.1.1 gets released.